# Core Data Int going in with correct value and coming out with wrong one - Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, int, nsnumber

Been trying to workout the issue for a while now. I am parsing data from a API and inputing it into my core data entity attribute which is a `Int`.

```
//Visit Details
if let dateInteger = element["date"] as? Int{
    println("RESPONSE OUTSTANDING DATE: \(dateInteger)")
//OUTPUTTING AS 1435586400
    visitEntity.dateDue = NSNumber(integer:dateInteger)
}
```

When fetching it I am using

```
//Fetch Vists and related Objects
        let currentVisits = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! VisitDetails
        println("TIMESTAMP INT \(currentVisits.dateDue)")
//Outputing as -14288
```

I'm pretty confused. I have tried it with various different output types but it isn't coming out with the correct value.

Comment: What is the attribute type in Core Data? Integer 16, by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can repro a similar problem, though the number I am seeing is 20320 not -14288.

Check to make sure that the dateDue attribute in your data model is defined large enough to hold the largest value returned by your API.

My guess is you might have defined it as Int16 instead of Int32 or Int64.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Don't understand why int16 would do this but I will read up on it.

Comment: Int16 means 16 bits are used to store the value. The largest value that can be stored in 16 bits is 2 raised to the power of 16, or 65536. If the integer is signed, then the max positive value is half that. When you try to store a value larger than that, what actually gets stored will be a smaller value, sometimes negative, based on how the bits line up. The higher order bits get truncated and your original value is lost.